# What do we know about the differential equation ${\mathrm{d}y\over\mathrm{d}x}= {Cy\over x}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, partial-differential-equations

What do we know about the differential equation ${\mathrm{d}y\over\mathrm{d}x}= {Cy\over x}$,

where: both $x$ and $y$ are undefined at $0$, constant $C\ge\frac{3}{2}$, finite, and assuming the constraint $-1<{\mathrm{d}y\over\mathrm{d}x}<1$?

Does it appear in other problems (e.g. math, physics)?  It is okay to extend into the complex plane if necessary to explain things.

Edit:
Thanks for the answers that reached the form $y=Kx^C$.  However, I need $x$ to be able to grow linearly (e.g. it may be time) without $y$ exploding.  So I am modifying this post.  Please take $-1<{\mathrm{d}y\over\mathrm{d}x}<1$ as a constraint and assume further that $C\ge{3\over 2}$.

I know it behaves like a charging curve $1-\mathbf{e}^{-x}$.  What else do we know?  From Fabio's comment, I guess there may be curve fitting situations with a variable power of $x$ in the denominator.

Comment: Your edit doesn't make much sense. It seems that you're asking a question which is different from what you *really* want to know. See “[the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)”.

Comment: Hi @HansLundmark, This equation did in fact show up in some crazy derivations recently.  I can't reasonably explain what happened in a post here, except that the origin or $0$ should be "forbidden", although if an extension satisfies the constraint it may still be meaningful.  I was surprised there was no obvious, well known results other than $y=Kx^C$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{Cy}{x}\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y}=\frac{C}{x}\mathrm{d}x\\
\int\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y}=\int\frac{C}{x}\mathrm{d}x\\
\ln(y)=C\cdot\ln(x)+C_1\\
y=\exp\left(C\cdot\ln(x)+C_1\right)\\
y=e^{C_1} x^C\\
y=k\cdot x^C
$$
Where $k>0$
The first step is not "legal" from a mathematical point of view, but in physics it is always done.

Comment: The fist step is legal and from  mathematical point of view. We just separate variables

Comment: Uhm.. nope, $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$ is the operator of differentiation. In physics, it's often thought of as a ratio of differentials, but it's not a real fraction, it's an operator (on the contrary, if we really have to be honest, it is the limit of an incremental ratio). We use a ratio as a notation, but there are also other notations: I might as well have written $D_x y$, $\partial_x y$ or $y'(x)$ but I would have taken more steps and it didn't seem like the case.

Comment: @FabioCaiazzo You're right, even my analysis professor always told us that you couldn't simplify differentials

Comment: @Efesto ahaha I know, I swear that the things I say I do not invent on the spot.

Comment: Well, I need $x$ to be able to grow linearly (e.g. time), without $y$ exploding.  Hence the assumption $-1<{\mathrm{d}y\over\mathrm{d}x}<1$.
May I know where such a differential equation is seen in physics?

Comment: @BucketHalfull virtually everywhere, from calculating electric fields to gravitational fields (at most it could change the power in the denominator)

Comment: The step from $\frac{1}{y} \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{C}{x}$ to row 4 is just the chain rule in reverse, and this is what justifies the manipulations done on rows 2 and 3.

Comment: Since the 1960s (nonstandard analysis), you can treat first-order differentials algebraically, and treat the derivative as a ratio of differentials.  If you alter the notation slightly, you can also do it for higher-order differentials as well.  With a tiny bit more modification, you can also do partial differentials algebraically.  See Fite's paper, "Total and Partial Differentials as Algebraically Manipulable Entities".  https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.07958

Comment: Ok, but I strongly doubt that someone who asks to solve a differential equation with separable variables is studying non-standard analyses or PDE, a little context come on, it's not that you have to show who knows more, otherwise next time find x²=-1 and start writing all the bases of the sedenions.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve more generally the first order equation $\frac{dy}{dx} = a(x)y$ (here with $a(x) = C/x$) on any interval where $a$ is well defined (here any interval that doesn't contain $0$). For this, consider $A$ a primitive of $a$ (here $A(x) = C\ln|x|$) and multiply both sides of the equation by $e^{-A}$,
$$
y'(x)e^{-A(x)} - a(x)e^{-A(x)}y(x) = 0.
$$
Now, notice that $-ae^{-A}$ is the derivative of $e^{-A}$ and use the formula $(uv)' = u'v + uv'$ to get,
$$
\frac{d}{dx}(ye^{-A}) = 0,
$$
Thus, there is a constant $K$ (that we can find using an initial condition on $y$) such that $ye^{-A} = K$, hence $y(x) = Ke^{A(x)}$. In your case, the set of solutions are the $y(x) = Ke^{C\ln|x|} = K|x|^C$ for a constant $K$ on $\mathbb{R}_+^*$ or $\mathbb{R}_-^*$.

However, I don't know if it has any application of physics.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to write an "answer".  Maybe you can tell me if anything is wrong.  Let's assume $x$ and $y$ are both positive.

If we look at the second derivative,
$$\begin{aligned}
y''&=\frac{xCy'-Cy}{x^2}\\&=\frac{C^2y-Cy}{x^2}\\&=\frac{Cy}{x}\cdot\frac{C-1}{x}
\end{aligned}$$
and it is always postive if $C\gt1$.  $y$ always blows up.

However, if we look at the discrete picture, take a small step $\Delta x$:
$$
\Delta y=\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\Delta x=\frac{Cy\Delta x}{x+\Delta x}
$$
That is crucial because we need a "new" $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{Cy}{x+\Delta x}$.
We want
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}&\lt\frac{Cy}{x}\\\frac{Cy\Delta x}{\Delta x(x+\Delta x)}&\lt\frac{Cy}{x}\\1+\frac{\Delta x}{x}&\gt1\\\frac{\Delta x}{x}&\gt0
\end{aligned}$$
which is trivially true.  And the conclusion is that, if $y$ cannot blow up, $x$ has to be discrete.  Is this correct?  If so, is $y$ bounded from above?

In the "crazy derivations" that had led to this question, everything was done in continuous.  Is there something in Analysis I should learn to understand what is going on?